# How to get real value of parameters in url

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have problem but I tried many solutions but it does not work .
Here is my code:

```
var params = '?DepartmentId=' + DepartmentId + '&DepartmentName=' + DepartmentName;
```

When I send params 'DepartmentName' with value 'R&D ABC' It only send 'R' to controller . 
I tried to encode this params but it does not work like this:

```
params = encodeURI(params);
```

but it still get 'R' instead of all value.

Please help me, thanks

Comment: Kindly provide the code that consumes `params` -- it's unclear where things might be getting url-encoded without more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, you should use [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) to encode parameter in url :

```
var params = '?DepartmentId=' + DepartmentId + '&DepartmentName=' + encodeURIComponent(DepartmentName);
```